# Android : what happens when I re-launch my app after a long break

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indicator

I'm developing an app where my Main Activity is a 3 tab actionBar. One of the tabs handles a ExpandableListView where I want the indicator to stay on the right, so in MainActivity I got this :

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (tab != null){
        lv.setIndicatorRightFunction(); //Sets indicator on the right side
    }
}
```

My problem is that sometimes, this function is not called and the indicator remains left! So I added setIndicatorRightFunction() in onResume() also and it seemed to work fine when my app is onPause().

The problem is when I go afk for a while, or switches on multiple other apps on my phone. Then, when I relaunch my App, the indicator appears on the left side ! So setIndicatorRightFunction() was not called! Is there another method where I can call this to solve my problem ? Am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT :

I figured out that the function eventually wasn't called because sometimes the tab equals null. Why ? How can I solve this ?

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tab = new tabFragment();
            return tab;
        }
    }
```

Aren't there any onResume() functions-like for fragments ? A solution that I can see, is to call my setIndicator function when my fragments is resumed/...

Comment: "So setIndicatorRightFunction() was not called! " Have you confirmed that this is the case, and not that the function was called but not producing the desired effect?

Comment: Fragment does have an onResume() method ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume()). Also, you may want to study Android's [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) to prevent random app blow-up.

Comment: onResume() in fragments was exactly what I needed. Thanks.